# Какие библиотеки c# лучше использовать для того чтобы автоматизировать действия в интернете

Tags: c#

Какие библиотеки c# лучше использовать для того чтобы автоматизировать какие то действия в интернете,чтобы не проделывать кучу однообразной работы,где все действия повторяются

Comment: Приведите примеры действий, пока вопросы выглядит слишком общим.

Comment: Для чего они мне нужны я не скажу,но есть очень похожий пример: к примеру допустим что нужно в браузерной игре сделать так,что бы твой персонаж сам к примеру убивал монстров,

Comment: Подход может отличаться, все зависит от архитектуры. Простые клики по координатам можно и через WinAPI делать. Но не факт, что именно на C# вам будет проще. Советую к прочтению некоторые статьи на хабре, для понимания взаимодействия с браузером. [\[1\]](https://habrahabr.ru/post/228607/) [\[2\]](https://habrahabr.ru/post/257619/) [\[3\]](https://habrahabr.ru/post/127444/)

Comment: @ЛаврикКан чем точнее задачу сформулируете, тем лучше будет ответ. Хотите написать бота для браузерной игры, так и скажите ) Дело в том, что обычный браузинг может очень сильно отличаться от игры. Например доступом к элементам страницы.

Comment: Хорошо,скажем так есть сайт по программированию,мне нужно что бы каждый день бот в определенное время заходил на сайт,входил в личный кабинет,и закидывал домашку

Comment: Используйте HttpWebRequest. Можно использовать сторонние библиотеки, такие как xnet.

Comment: Принцип работы довольно прост: подключаетесь к серверу, отправляете данные авторизации в нужном формате (логин пароль из формы ввода например), загружаете нужную страницу, отправляете нужные файлы, отправляете запрос на отправку. Не забываем после каждого запроса читать ответ...